# Systemd, Running service at startup

Tags: linux, services, systemd

Im trying to run some custom service at system startup using systemd. The service itself is working well and I can stop start and restart it manually and works, but when it comes to enable it at system startup the service fails,I have previously enabled it using

```
sudo systemctl enable opimonitor
```

The service is this.

```
[Unit]
Description=Opi Monitor service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/arraiz/OPIstatus/start.sh
#Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/home/arraiz/OPIstatus
User=arraiz
Group=arraiz

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the start.sh is this.

```
git pull && python3 main.py
```

the log from status is

```
● opimonitor.service - Opi Monitor service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/opimonitor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-31 14:55:43 CEST; 1min 29s ago
  Process: 1114 ExecStart=/home/arraiz/OPIstatus/start.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1114 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: opimonitor.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: opimonitor.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: Stopped Opi Monitor service.
Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: opimonitor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: opimonitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 31 14:55:43 orangepipcplus systemd[1]: Failed to start Opi Monitor service.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this question on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/736624/systemd-service-automatic-restart-after-startlimitinterval it is not exactly the same issue, but I think the info there will help with the restarting too early problem.

Answer (score 0):

this in the service file under [Unit] tag did the trick

```
After=printer.target network.target multi-user.target
```